# How to prove that f(z) is constant over an open connected set?

Tags: complex-analysis

From Basic Complex Analysis 3rd edition

1.5 #16

a) Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be an analytic function defined on a connected open set A. If $au(x,y)+bv(x,y)=c$ in A, where a,b,c are real constants not all 0, prove that f(z) is constant in A.

My attempt at a proof:

In order to show that f(z) is constant over A, we need to show f'(z)=0 over A. We're given that $au(x,y)+bv(x,y)=c$ in A, so we proceed by taking partial derivatives:

$a(du/dx)+b(dv/dx)=0$ and $a(du/dy)+b(dv/dy)=0$

Since f(z) is analytic, we can use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to write:

$a(du/dx)-b(du/dy)=0$ and $a(du/dy)+b(du/dx)=0$

We can solve this as a system of equations with two unknowns $(du/dx,du/dy)$. The matrix of coefficients gives $a^2+b^2=c$ which are real constants that cannot all be zero from the statement of the problem. Therefore $du/dx=du/dy=0$ and $f'(z)=du/dx+i(dv/dx)=0$ on A. Since A is connected, f is constant.

Is this proof valid?

b) Is the result obtained in (a) still valid if a,b,c are complex constants?

Comment: I don't see how you get $a^2+b^2=c$, but since not all of $a,b,c$ are $0$, it follows that $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$, and hence the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are $0$. Re b), look at the real and imaginary part of the equation.